# Update Variable in TeamCity powershell script

Tags: powershell, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I am trying to update an enviroment variable in TeamCity using Powershell script. However, it does not update the value of the variable. How can I do this?

Below is my current code which gets the currentBuildNumber fine:

```
$currentBuildNumber = "%env.currentBuildNumber%"
$newBuildNumber = ""
Write-Output $currentBuildNumber
If ($currentBuildNumber.StartsWith("%MajorVersion%") -eq "True")
{
 $parts = $currentBuildNumber.Split(".")
 $parts[2] = ([int]::Parse($parts[2]) + 1) + ""
 $newBuildNumber = $parts -join "."
}
Else
{
 $newBuildNumber = '%MajorVersion%.1'
}

//What I have tried
$env:currentBuildNumber = $newBuildNumber
Write-Host "##teamcity[env.currentBuildNumber '$newBuildNumber']"
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='currentBuildNumber' value='$newBuildNumber']"
```

Comment: For my own reference, see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity for more info about the ## notation

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

`"##teamcity[setParameter name='env.currentBuildNumber' value='$newBuildNumber']"`

(note the env. prefix in the name)

Also, you can try to increase the PowerShell std out column default (80 using TeamCity's command runner).  If your service message is longer than that, then TeamCity will fail to parse it.

```
if ($env:TEAMCITY_VERSION) {
    $host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(8192,50)
}
```

Comment: sorry my fault all the names are the same at it still does not work refer to my updated question

Comment: Are you sure you need the WriteHost?  Try it just in quotes

Comment: Will give it a try shortly but Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$newBuildNumber']" works

Comment: I just ran a test locally and double quoting the service message does update the environment variable...

Comment: I have updated my current code and it is not working what is different between mine and the code that worked when you tested it?

Comment: Ignore the Write-Host bit, that was a red herring. I just tried again with and it still works.  What do you see in your build log - have you searched for the service message text?

Comment: You may also want to try increasing the std out column width (80 by default in TeamCity). - see edit to answer